# Spring security data unable to fetch the results

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch all the orders if the user role is `ROLE_ADMIN`, else fetch me only the orders matching the customer id.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query("select o from Order o inner join o.customer c where c.id = ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '%' :  principal.id}")
    Page<Order> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

I am getting the below response

```
Parameter value [%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The id of a customer is supposed to be a number (`Long`). But when the role matches `ROLE_ADMIN`, you are returning a char: `%`.

I think the person that suggested this solution was copying from another example that was using a `LIKE` operation and didn't realized that it's wrong in this case.

I think you can try something like this:

```
@Query("select o from Order o inner join o.customer c where true = ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')} or c.id = ?#{principal.id}")
```

But I don't know if this is the right approach

Comment: I referred to this link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjlDbIIJBi8&t=2280s

Comment: Is there a way to fetch all the records if the role matches `ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: I've just noticed that the YouTube video is from 2015. I think you should look for something more recent. These are the examples from the Spring Security repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/java-configuration

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that will work but I don't know if it's the right approach to use with Spring Security. Good luck